# Read response stream via XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have the code that should read response stream and fill progress bar. Server response is correct. The issue is `updateProgress` event is not fired.

```
function load_binary_resource(url) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', url, false);
    req.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress);
    req.overrideMimeType('text\/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
    req.send(null);
    if (req.status != 200) return '';
    return req.responseText;
}
function updateProgress (oEvent) {
    if (oEvent.lengthComputable) {
        console.log('loading');
        var percentComplete = oEvent.loaded / oEvent.total * 100;
        // ...
    } else {
        console.log('something happening');
    }
}
```

Comment: it might be error-ing out for some reason. Is there some error handler you could add AND check for sure the call is NOT error-ing out. `progress` would work only if data is streaming in ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your,

```
req.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress);
```

as,

```
req.upload.addEventListener('progress', updateProgress, false);
```

Progress events exist for both download and upload transfers. The download events are fired on the XMLHttpRequest object itself. The upload events are fired on the XMLHttpRequest.upload object as per [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress)

Hope this helps!